# Adding new files to the Solution file for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, projects-and-solutions

I have an already existing solution file for my live website. If I add any new files(.aspx page) in my project, I have to explicitly add those new files to the solution by right clicking on the project -> Add -> Existing item -> selecting the files.

Now, after adding the files for the first time, I added few more files later. During that time, I found that the files which I added in my first deployment were missing and I had to add the old files again with the new ones?

Am I doing anything wrong or is that the way it works? Do I need to add all the new files explicitly to the solution every time before publishing to the server?

Comment: Are you using a web site (file->New Web Site), or a Web Application Project (File->New Project)?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Web Application project

Comment: they are not missing literally are they .. or did you use the project solution to view all files and the hidden one's did you select include in project..?

Comment: Exactly how did you add the files? BTW, web application project is the right way to go.

Comment: The missing files are present in the project but when I publish the solution, they are not present in the solution. This gives me error when I try to navigate to those newly added pages. I have to again add those existing items in my solution.

Comment: I added the new files by right clicking on the project -> add -> new items ->   Web User Control form.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? I am facing this issue during each of my production deployments. Currently due to less number of newly added files, it's not a big deal but as the number of files increase, it will be a big trouble. @MethodMan

Comment: when you say that the files are present in the solution did you then right click and select `Include` option..?

Comment: I add the new files to the solution by right clicking on the project -> Add -> Existing item -> selecting the files.
I am not sure about the Include option? Do I need to do that? Can you please explain more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue which I was facing was because my project's ".csproj" file was not getting updated while deploying the project. It is ".csproj" file which keeps track of all the files which have being added newly. Once I updated the particular file in my production environment, I was able to see all my project files and it didn't require manual intervention. Thanks all for your help.